# Parameter is not deserialized at service end

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, serialization

I have created a net.tcp WCF service. Below are data contract and service contract.

```
[DataContract]    
public class DBParametersDataContract
{
    [DataMember]
    public string  ProcedureName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Entity.DBParameter> Params { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string  UserName { get; set; }
}

public class DBParameter
{
    public DBParameter()
    {

    }

    public string  ParameterName { get; set; }
    public object  ParameterValue { get; set; }

    public System.Data.DbType  ParamerterType { get; set; }
}


[ServiceContract]
interface IDBOperationServiceContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    string DBReadOperation(DBParametersDataContract param);

    [OperationContract]
    DBWriteOutputDataContract DBWriteOperation(DBParametersDataContract param);
}
```

Here is my Service Implementation:

```
public string DBReadOperation(DBParametersDataContract param)
{
    try
    {
        return param.ProcedureName;
        //return new DBReadOutputDataContract();
        //Helper.DBHelper dbh = new Helper.DBHelper();
        //return dbh.ReadFromDataBase(param);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

}
```

Service is getting called but it seems that parameter (data contract) which is passed to service is not getting de-serialized.

```
Service.DBOperationServiceContractClient service = new Service.DBOperationServiceContractClient();
var parm = new Service.DBParametersDataContract()
{
    ProcedureName = "AuthenticateUser",
    Params = new List<Service.Entity.DBParameter>() 
    { 
        new Service.Entity.DBParameter() 
        {
            ParameterName="@Name", 
            ParameterValue=txtLoging.Text,
            ParamerterType= DbType.String 
        } 
    }
    //Params = new Tuple<string, object, System.Data.DbType>[]
    //{new Tuple<string, object, DbType>("@Name",txtLoging.Text,DbType.String )}
    //Params = new Service.TupleOfstringanyTypeDbType3NwETDfr[]
    //{ new Service.TupleOfstringanyTypeDbType3NwETDfr() { m_Item1 = "Name", m_Item2 = txtLoging.Text, m_Item3 = Service.DbType.String } }
};
var output= service.DBReadOperation(parm);
```

When the service is called as above it calls the service as I can see the log in service trace viewer and a file which I am writing at server side.

It returns null.

But if I return hard coded value from the service I am able to get the return value in client.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely the result of passing an object in the **DataContract**.

You will need to specify the appropriate types in the **ServiceKnownType** Attribute in order to correctly pass the "object".

From MSDN:

> The declared type for the information to be transmitted is Object. Because every type inherits from Object, and it cannot be known in advance which type is actually sent, the receiving endpoint cannot determine in advance the data contract for the transmitted data. This is a special case of the first item: Every data contract derives from the default, a blank data contract that is generated for Object.

References:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx